# How to switch the layout of a hardware keyboard without changing language?

Tags: keyboard, localization

I have bought German T-Mobile G1 (HTC Dream), and thus I have German hardware keyboard. In stock firmware I used English language, but the keyboard was still German - that was OK. I got used to that layout, and all was well.

Then I upgraded firmware to CM6.0, keyboard was still German.

Then I went restored backup of stock 1.6 firmware, and suddenly android thinks that I have US keyboard. I can't type quickly because the symbols printed on the keyboard are for German keyboard, but the keystrokes generate characters for US English.

Is there a file containing the key mappings, that I can save using adb with correct layout and restore on the firmware with wrong layout? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there any settings for the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

There is no file that I know of for changeing keyboard layout.

You might want to try to change the settings for your phone to English and then back to German.  That might help reseting the keyboard layout, depending how HTC have set up the firmware the you used when you reinstalled the phone.

If that doesn't work, you could try to use `adb` from Googles Android developer site.  There you can set Localization for your phone without using the menu in settings.  That *should* be the same thing though.

- Tells how to change Localization on a device through menu and using `adb` command (which is advanced!).
  [Android Developers Dev Guide, device](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#device)
- Also some instructions how to change/test localization on an Android device when you test their Tutorial program on Localization.
  [Android Developers Resources, test localized](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html#test_localized)

If this doesn't work, you could always try to install another software keyboard from the Market or reinstall the Android firmware in the phone.

Comment: thanks, but downloading another software keyboard isn't relevant, as I was having problems with hardware keyboard layout

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to flash a stock German ROM, and completely wipe out the broken settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overwriting keyboard layout in my ROM backup file from stock german ROM, and flashing the new "backup" back.